# Time restricted service

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency, queue, policy

i'm developing an app that make requests to the Musicbrainz webservice. I read in the musicbrainz manual to not make more than one request per second to the webservice or the client IP will be blocked.

What architecture do you suggest in order to make this restriction transparent to the service client.

- I would like to call a method (getAlbuns for example) and it should only make the request 1sec after the last request.
- I also want to call 10 request at once and the service should handle the queueing, returning the results when avaiable (Non-blocking).

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're creating a desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the required delay between invocations, I'd suggest a [`java.util.Timer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). `Timer` is very simple, and perfectly adequate for *this* use case. But if additional scheduling requirements are identified later, a single `Executor` could handle all of them. In either case, use fixed-delay method, not a fixed-rate method.

The recurring task [polls](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#poll()) a concurrent queue for a request object. If there is a pending request, the task executes it, and returns the result via a callback. The query for the service and the callback to invoke are members of the request object.

The application keeps a reference to the shared queue. To schedule a request, simply add it to the queue.

---

Just to clarify, if the queue is empty when the scheduled task is executed, no request is made. The simple approach would be just to end the task, and the scheduler will invoke the task one second later to check again.

However, this means that it could take up to one second to start a task, even if no requests have been processed lately. If this unnecessary latency is intolerable, writing your own thread is probably preferable to using `Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. In your own timing loop, you have more control over the scheduling if you choose to block on an empty queue until a request is available. The built-in timers aren't guaranteed to wait a full second after the previous execution *finished*; they generally schedule relative to the *start* time of the task.

If this second case is what you have in mind, your `run()` method will contain a loop. Each iteration starts by [blocking](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()) on the queue until a request is received, then recording the time. After processing the request, the time is checked again. If the time difference is less than one second, [sleep](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) for the the remainder. This setup assumes that the one second delay is required between the start of one request and the next. If the delay is required between the end of one request and the next, you don't need to check the time; just sleep for one second.

One more thing to note is that the service might be able to accept multiple queries in a single request, which would reduce overhead. If it does, take advantage of this by blocking on `take()` for the first element, then using [`poll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), perhaps with a very short blocking time (5 ms or so), to see if the application is making any more requests. If so, these can be bundled up in a single request to the service. If `queue` is a `BlockingQueue<? extends Request>`, it might look something like this:

```
    Collection<Request> bundle = new ArrayList<Request>();
    bundle.add(queue.take());
    while (bundle.size() < BUNDLE_MAX) {
      Request req = queue.poll(EXTRA, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (req == null)
        break;
      bundle.add(req);
    }
    /* Now make one service request with contents of "bundle". */
```

Comment: But I don't want to make a request every second. I want to make sure, when the client make a request, that it only execute 1sec after the last one.

Comment: Right, Marcio. I didn't mean to imply that; I'll update my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a local "proxy service" which your local clients will call.

The local proxy will receive requests and pass it on to the real service. But only at the rate of one message per second.

How you do this depends very much on the tecnoligy available to you.

The simplest would be a mutithreaded java service with a static and synchronised LastRequestTime long;" timestamp variable. (Although you would need some code acrobatics to keep your requests in sequence).

A more sophisticated service could have worker threads receiving the requests and placing them on a queue with a single thread picking up the requests and passing them on to the real service.